# Given a sample space, event space, and probability measure of two sets. Determine probability of a set.

Tags: probability

1.2 Event spaces (10 pt)
Consider a probability space where the sample space is Ω = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and the event space is 2^Ω . Assume that we only know that the probability measure P· satisfies

P({0, 1, 2}) = 1/2

P({2,3,4}) = 1/2

• If possible, determine P({1, 2}). 
 I don't think this set is possible with and, or, or not operations.

• If possible, determine P({0, 1}).

For this I think it is P(A) - P(A or B) = .5- (.5*.5) = .25 but I am not sure if that is correct. Can somebody help me understand this problem?

Comment: $P(\{0,1\}) = P(\Omega) - P(\{2,3,4\}) = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5$. I don't think you can get $P({1,2})$.

Comment: You write $P(A~\text{or}~B)$ which is $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  I think you were thinking of $P(A\cap B)$ for your $.5\cdot .5$ calculation **however**, and I cannot stress this enough, $P(A\cap B)$ is *not* equal to $P(A)\cdot P(B)$ in the general case.  The probability of the intersection of two events is equal to the product of the probabilities of the events *if and only if* the two events are independent, which we do not know anything about the independence for this specific problem.